# Make an android phone to pose as a Bluetooth input device (mouse or keyboard)

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to make an android phone app that will make the phone implement and broadcast the required data to pose as a Bluetooth mouse so that other devices (PC, XBOX, PS, Other android devices) could recognize it as a mouse or a keyboard ?

Comment: Maybe, what have you tried?

Comment: That is exactly the problem, i couldn't find any info on how to start... the Bluetooth docs in Google describe something on the "Profiles" object but is seems not to implement a mouse profile or a keyboard profile. so basically i'm asking if it is possible because i could not find any other source that will describe it.

Comment: You might have to delve into the bluetooth specs and just try it out yourself... Perhaps you'll be the first to do it, and you can make a blog post or something like that about it so others will be able to learn from your experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just googled it...try this apk and let us know your views:https://code.google.com/p/androhid/

Comment: For any causal Googlers *(like myself)*, the page linked says: `This application needs a` **`rooted`** `android device.`

Answer (score 2):

blueputdroid and androhid are supposed to be able to do this. Both require root.

I couldn't get either app to work on CyanogenMod 11

## blueputdroid

blueputdroid is supposed to work best on old versions of android as google supposedly changed something in their bluetooth stack in 4.2 that made it incompatible. From what i understand from this [thread on xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=940511&page=55) it doesn't seem like there's any plans on supporting newer Android versions

## androhid

Isn't available in the play store or f-droid repos. Download apk from: https://code.google.com/p/androhid/

I couldn't get this to work. Crashed with "unexpected error" on launch.